# Does zero padding affect my ECDSA signature?

Tags: ecc

I have data varying between 32 bytes and 48 bytes for ECDSA signature i.e. it can be 33,34,35...etc..bytes upto 48 bytes. (Hashing is not considered in this implementation as per PKCS: ECDSA without Hash) So, the solution is that if data is 34 bytes, then remaining 14 bytes can be zero padding so that 48 bytes length is ready in order to use ECDSA with 384 bitlength curve.

Question: Will this padding affect my ECDSA signature? I mean the signature obtained using 34 bytes message and 48 bytes messages(obtained after padding) would it be same or not if it uses the same 384 bitlength ECC curve. Is it secure to do so?